# On the singularity of Biot-Savart's law inside a current-carrying conductor

Tags: singularities, magnetostatics

When using Biot-Savart's law to compute magnetic flux density on a field point away from a current source point, the integrand is finite; however when using it to compute the field inside the source where "R" the distance between field and source is zero the integrand is singular.

All three versions, i.e. for linear currents, surface and volume currents this problem arises.
$$ B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_V \frac{J_v \times a_R}{R^2}dv $$
$$ B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_S \frac{J_s \times a_R}{R^2}ds $$
$$ B = \frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_C \frac{Idl \times a_R}{R^2} $$
where $J_v$ and $J_s$ are the volume and surface current densities. $a_R$ is the unit vector pointing from source to field point.

Does the formula states that the magnetic flux density is infinitely large inside the source? Because this seems impossible.

I encountered this problem when I was trying to find the flux density on a surface current. The same issue happens when calculating the self-inductance using Neumann's formula.

Comment: The same sort of singular integrand arises when you calculate the electric potential of a charge distribution:$$V(\mathbf{r}) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \iiint \frac{\rho(\mathbf{r}')}{|\mathbf{r} - \mathbf{r}'|} \, d v.$$It might be worth investigating the question in that context, since it doesn't involve the complications of dealing with vectors and cross products.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Could you provide a reference? I could only find some articles regarding integral formulation with very complex numerical algorithms (e.g. Galerkin, Ritz) which I don't have insight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does the formula states that the magnetic flux density is infinitely large inside the source? Because this seems impossible.

This situation occurs only when the current distribution is curve-like, with zero thickness (or point-like, due to moving charged point-like particle). Then magnetic field *diverges* at the line (or the point). This does not necessarily mean it is "infinitely large" at that line or point.

It is "infinitely large" in the sense its magnitude diverges to infinity when one approaches to the current line or point from any direction. But there is no single limit, because direction of magnetic field always depends on the direction of approach. This is a mathematical fact. It is not correct to say this is impossible in mathematics.

This means that we have a discontinuous magnetic field, not infinite magnetic field. In fact, magnetic field definition can be sometimes completed even in that point of singularity. For example, if there is other source of magnetic field, this acts on the line/point, and we can define total magnetic field at the line/point as the external magnetic field due to the other source.

If the current distribution is planar, i.e. current is running in a plane, then there may not be a divergence at all. If finite line element in the plane, perpendicular to the current, is associated with finite current passing through it, then even infinite plane with net infinite current will create finite magnetic field in both half-spaces. This follows from Ampere's law; magnetic intensity times length of a line segment equals net current intensity associated with that length.

Comment: "This means that we have a discontinuous magnetic field, not infinite magnetic field". If the magnetic field is finite and just discontinuous, How can we find it? (e.g. on both sides of a surface current). Is it possible using Biot-Savart's law? if not, how else?

Comment: Yes, use the Biot-Savart law.

Comment: I conducted a simple case: a long planar conductor and the integral goes to infinity.

Comment: Which integral? Field of current running in infinite plane with finite current density produces finite magnetic field.

Comment: The Biot-Savart integral. I emphasize that the field point $x_f$ is exactly on the surface current.
$$\vec B(x_f)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{xs1}^{xs2}\frac{J_s\vec a_z\times (x_f-x_s)\vec a_x}{(x_f-x_s)^3}dx_s$$
the surface current is a horizontal surface bounded to source points $x_{s1}<x_s<x_{s2}$ and the current is directed along z-axis. Is my integration correct?

Comment: So the current is running only in the finite width stripe, not in the whole infinite plane?

Comment: If current is running in direction of the $z$-axis, then the integration must go over the $z$ variable as well, to go over all surface elements with current in them. It is not enough to integrate just over single coordinate, when current exists in a plane.

Comment: If the field is discontinuous and finite, it has to have one-sided limits. For example we know that $B(x_0,y_0)$ is meaningless since the point is exactly located on the discontinuity, but $B(x_0+h,y_0+h)$ (h is infinitesimal) must exist.

Comment: Is this correct now?
$$\vec B(x_f)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{xs1}^{xs2}\frac{J_s\vec a_z\times ((x_f-x_s)\vec a_x + (0-z_s)\vec a_z)}{((x_f-x_s)^2+(0-z_s)^2)^{3/2}}dx_sdz_s$$

Comment: Yes, one sided limit should exist. The integral looks correct, provided $J_s dx_s$ is current intensity associated with length $dx_s$. That is, if $\int_{x_{s1}}^{x_{s2}} J_s  dx_s$ is net current running through the stripe.

Comment: Now we can see that the integrand is singular in $x_f=x_s$ and $z_s=0$, i.e. when the field point is on a source point. and thus it is not integrable (Or maybe it is but through complicated mathematics?)

Comment: Dr. Lalinsky, your answers were quite helpful in physical viewpoint. I assume the following mathematical problem:
$$\vec B(x_f)=\frac{\mu_0}{4\pi}\lim_{y_f \to 0}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{xs1}^{xs2}\frac{J_s\vec a_z\times ((x_f-x_s)\vec a_x + (y_f-0)\vec a_y + (0-z_s)\vec a_z)}{((x_f-x_s)^2+(y_f-0)^2+(0-z_s)^2)^{3/2}}dx_sdz_s$$
should be asked from a mathematican. I assume I must ask we know the limit exist but how can we find it. am I right?

Comment: I am not a Dr. If you want to go this way, then yes, it is a mathematical question about this kind of integral. But it is easier to analyze first the idealized case where the current runs through the whole infinite plane. One can use the Ampere law and symmetry of the system to find the fact that magnetic field is uniform and does not depend on distance from the plane, so the one-sided limit is the same. Then you can try to analyze the harder case of the finite-width stripe. I expect that the one-sided limit of magnetic field will be the same as the field of the infinite plane with same $J$.

Comment: I already solved a simple problem: a long empty cylinder, using Ampere's law to get the physical understanding. Now I must go for the difficult ones using Biot-Savart's law. Thank you again for taking time.

Answer (score 1):

It's a typical problem in non-quantum electromagnetism.

This theory simply cannot describe self-interaction, so when you try to study the field too close to its source (in the point-like case in particular), the results may lose meaning. You're simply stepping outside the validity domain of the theory.

You can't always see it in the Biot-Savart integral, since an integral can be finite even if the function being integrated has singularities. But it's easy to find examples where the field, after computation, does have singularities near its source (wire, empty cylinder...)

However, be careful about another source of singularities that has nothing to do with self-interaction. In the context of classical electrodynamics, linear and surface currents are defined as the limit of a volumetric current when one or two of its dimensions are flattened to zero. This limit introduces artificial discontinuities.

For example, consider an infinite plane with a non-zero thickness $e$ with volumetric currents going in a single direction inside.

- If you compute the magnetic field it generates, you get a result with no singularity anywhere.
- Take the limit $e\to 0$ while maintaining the value of the current inside. You go from a volumetric to a surface model for the current, and the generated field become singular on the plane itself.

This singularity simply comes from the fact that you're neglecting the distance over which the field varies from one side of the plane to the other. It's called an *artifact*, because it doesn't mean anything physical, it's only a problem arising from your choice of model.

Comment: Brilliant answer. I always doubted about the linear/surface currents being artifact. That leaves us only volume currents which introduce no singularity in the field. However my doubts increased when I learned about equivalent surface currents for ferromagnetic materials. because the parallel component of flux density suddenly changes. in this case, should we expect that flux density is meaningless on the surface of iron? at least its parallel component to the boundary.

Comment: When a current is described as surface current, its flux (as a two-dimensional integral) is no longer defined and must be replaced with a one-dimensional integral over a segment (typically perpendicular to the current). I have, in practice, never seen this integral used anywhere.

Comment: Consider the case of long empty cylinder with surface thickness $e$. I excited it with a constant 1A current directed longitudinally. Then decreased the thickness as you mentioned. the results show that the magnetic field on its outer/inner surface maintained the same. the magnetic field inside the thickness exhibited the discontinuity  more and more as the thickness was decreasing. Can we conclude that for a surface current the magnetic field is always discontinuous? Can Biot-Savart's law prove it?